# Application-level load balancing technique

Tags: c

We have some hardware which is processing n messages and vendor is asking for 3n messages. We have to expose only IP to outside world to push protocol-level interaction messages.

Our solution that we have now is that if one client connects one process we are spawning to receive the messages. We cannot change our architecture to have one receiver to only receive messages and then give to processing entities. The only option we have is to have similar hardware of n pieces.

Initial authentication has to happen to receive messages. A big challenge only can be exposed to outside world.

Please make suggestions on this.  By 'protocol level interaction', I mean to say is SMPP.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have this:

```
IP addr=A
--------
|       |  n messages
| HW box|-------------> Endpoint
|       |
---------
```

You re-architecture it to this:

```
IP addr=internal1
--------
|       |  n messages
| HW box|-----------\
|       |            |
---------            |
IP addr=internal2    |
--------             |    IP addr = A
|       |  n messages \ -------- 
| HW box|-------------> | Proxy |
|       |             / |       |--------> Endpoint
---------            |  ---------
IP addr=internal3    |
--------             |
|       |  n messages|
| HW box|-----------/
|       |
---------

IP addr=A
```

You'll have to implement the Proxy, which will need to have an SMPP stack, and speak SMPP to the outside Endpoint as well as to the 3 HW boxes.

It'll have to terminate(or initiate) the connection to the 3 HW boxes, and expose just 1 connection to the outside world. The IP addresses of the HW boxes can be on its own private network.